# What's 'hypothetical' about 'hypothetical imperatives'?

Tags: kant

At the [39 minute 32 seconds juncture,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rv-4aUbZxQ) **hypothetical imperatives** are introduced by Prof Michael Sandel, *Justice: ...*, Episode 06: "MIND YOUR MOTIVE".
I also tried  p 515 of 692, *Philosophy & Ethics For Dummies 2 eBook Bundle*:

> A ***hypothetical imperative*** is a command that you give yourself if you have a certain goal.

Yet I don't unerstand what's **hypothetical** about all this?
Footnote: [This explanation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/53628/8712) worsened my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of an imperative, and it's qualification as hypothetical and categorical is most easily understood by examining Kants *Groundwork of a Metaphysics of Morality*; he writes:

> All imperatives command either hypothetically or categorically:
>
> the former represent the practical neccessity of a possible action to attain something else that one wills, or might will; the categorical represents an action that is objectively necessary in itself, without reference to another end.

Earlier he explains:

> A law to be called moral must be universally and neccessarily valid; a law should not be merely for this or that human being, or this or that nation; but for all rational beings.

Thus a hypothetical imperative would be, for example, if you (your actual self, not the general you) are at Canary Wharf underground station and about to go up the escalator to ground level; when you see that the person ahead of you is a young mother who is having trouble getting her pram onto the escalator; and there is no one else with her to help; thus you offer your help, which is gracefully accepted.

Here the situation is *specific*; and thus the imperative is *hypothetical* - it *ought* to be done.

A categorical imperative would be for the state to provide schooling - legally provided via private or public institutions, or some mixture; as all rational beings at some point are children and require schooling; here the situation is *general* and thus the imperative is *categorical*: it *must* be done.

Another way of examining these two situations is to examine the *consequences* if they are not:

In the first situation all mothers who decide to travel through Canary Wharf Stn with a pram and no one with them will be left to themselves to struggle as best as they can with the escalator; London will carry on, as will the nation.

In the second situation, no schooling of any kind is provided; the kids are left to themselves at home (parents aren't allowed to provide schooling - as this is a form of private schooling) or on the streets; it won't be long before London, and the nation descends into chaos.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

It is hypothetical because it hypothetically is in force all the time, because it establishes a relation between a specific end and specific means, which (in theory, based on our knowledge about the world) is always "correct". But its effectiveness is reduced to the specific situations where it is applyable, therefore it is not an imperative that is categorical, i.e. effective in every single act, but hypothetical, i.e. only effective *if* we want to achieve a specific end.

In the end, the hypothetical refers to the big **IF** thought within a hypothetical imperative. Like in "**IF** my assumptions are correct, my hypotheses (i.e. the explanatory part of it) is also correct." And the analogy goes further: Just as our hypotheses in science, hypothetical imperatives have to be based on empirical knowledge and are therefore limited by what we (are able to) know about the world and the theoretical relations we infer from it, e.g. causation. This may be wrong and that's the main difference to the categorical imperative, which qua being a priori is necessarily correct.

**Textual Support from GMM**

Ak. 414:

> Because every practical law represents a possible action as good, and
>   therefore as necessary for a subject practically determinable by reason, all
>   imperatives are formulas of the determination of action, which is necessary
>   in accordance with the principle of a will which is good in some way. **Now
>   if the action were good merely as a means to something else, then the
>   imperative is hypothetical**; if it is represented as good in itself, hence necessary, as the principle of the will, in a will that in itself accords with reason, then it is categorical.

So basically, it contains a condition: **If and only if** you want to achieve this end, you should use these means.

Ak. 414-5:

> The hypothetical imperative thus says only that the action is good for
>   some possible or actual aim. In the first case it is a *problematically* [later technical, 20:200)],
>    in the
>   second an *assertorically* practical principle.

This endorses the point about being "in force all the time hypothetically": It is always correct, but as long as you do not actually want to achieve the end, it is merely technical (it gives you means to a specific end), if you do, it becomes assertorical (in force without further ado).